# Foreground Location Service Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, service, location

I'm trying to make a Running app for Android in Kotlin, and it should draw a route which person has already ran, but I've encountered with issue that there is not possibility to update UI while app is in foreground. So I came up with an idea that I can collect Location into some mutableList and then draw it. First question: Is it correct approach? Second question: If it's correct, how to implement it, because I'm encounterint with issue that none of my implementations of service are executing(example of one of implementations below).

```
class RunningActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mapFragment: SupportMapFragment
    lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    var myLatitude: Double = 0.0
    var myLongitude: Double = 0.0
    private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
    private var isStarted : Boolean = false
    private lateinit var runningBar : View
    private lateinit var stopRunButton : View
    private lateinit var timerView : TextView
    lateinit var polyline: Polyline
    private lateinit var locationRequest : LocationRequest
    private val handler = Handler()
    private var secondsPassed = 0
    var totalDistanceInMeters: Float = 0f
    var lastLocation: Location? = null
    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView

    private lateinit var locationTrackingService: LocationTrackingService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_running)

        timerView = findViewById(R.id.timerid)
        stopRunButton = findViewById(R.id.stoprun)
        runningBar = findViewById(R.id.runningbar)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        if (!isStarted) {
            showPopupMenu()
        }
        stopRunButton.setOnClickListener{
            isStarted = false
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed()
            return
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
        }, 2000)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
        googleMap = map
        enableMyLocation()

        try {
            val success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                    this, R.raw.map_style
                )
            )

            if (!success) {
                Log.e("MapActivity", "Style parsing failed.")
            }
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            Log.e("MapActivity", "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
        }
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 1000

        permissionCheck()
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
                    p0.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                        myLatitude = location.latitude
                        myLongitude = location.longitude

                        val userLocation = LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude)
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15f))
                    }
                }
            },
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
        val uiSettings = googleMap.uiSettings
        uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

        polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions().width(10f).color(R.color.dark_green))
    }

    private fun enableMyLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            googleMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
                true
            }

            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                val location: Location? = task.result
                if (location != null) {
                    myLatitude = location.latitude
                    myLongitude = location.longitude

                    val userLocation = LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude)
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15f))
                }
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ), PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION = 1001
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enableMyLocation()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun showPopupMenu() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_popup_menu, null)

        bottomNavigationView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationViewRunning)

        builder.setView(dialogView)
        val dialog = builder.create()

        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)

        val layoutParams = dialog.window?.attributes
        layoutParams?.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        layoutParams?.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        dialog.window?.attributes = layoutParams

        dialog.setCancelable(false)

        dialog.show()

        val popupButton: Button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.getingrs)
        popupButton.setOnClickListener {
            isStarted = true
            runningBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            stopRunButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dialog.dismiss()
            startTimer()
            drawRoute()
        }
        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.runningMode

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> {
                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                    true
                }
                R.id.runningMode -> true
                R.id.settings -> {
                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                    true
                }
                else -> true
            }
        }
    }
    private val updateTextRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(secondsPassed.toLong())
            val minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(secondsPassed.toLong()) % 60
            val seconds = secondsPassed % 60
            timerView.text = String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d", hours, minutes, seconds)

            secondsPassed++

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
    private fun startTimer() {
        handler.post(updateTextRunnable)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateTextRunnable)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun drawRoute(){
        permissionCheck()
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                        myLatitude = location.latitude
                        myLongitude = location.longitude

                        val newLatLng = LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude)
                        val points = polyline.points
                        points.add(newLatLng)
                        polyline.points = points

                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng, 15f))

                        if (lastLocation != null) {
                            val distance = lastLocation!!.distanceTo(location)
                            totalDistanceInMeters += distance

                            val speed = location.speed

                            updateDistanceAndSpeed(totalDistanceInMeters, speed)
                        }
                        lastLocation = location
                    }
                }
            },
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    }

    //Try for function is LocationTrackingService was working
//    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
//    fun drawRoute(){
//    locationTrackingService = LocationTrackingService()
//    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, LocationTrackingService::class.java)
//    startService(serviceIntent)
//        while (true){
//            val location = locationTrackingService.getLocationList()
//            if (location.isNotEmpty()) {
//                myLatitude = location[0].latitude
//                myLongitude = location[0].longitude
//
//                val newLatLng = LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude)
//                val points = polyline.points
//                points.add(newLatLng)
//                polyline.points = points
//
//                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng, 15f))
//
//                if (lastLocation != null) {
//                    val distance = lastLocation!!.distanceTo(location[0])
//                    totalDistanceInMeters += distance
//
//                    val speed = location[0].speed
//
//                    updateDistanceAndSpeed(totalDistanceInMeters, speed)
//                }
//                lastLocation = location[0]
//                locationTrackingService.removeLocation(location[0])
//            }
//        }
//    }
    private fun updateDistanceAndSpeed(distanceInMeters: Float, speed: Float) {
        val distanceInKm = distanceInMeters / 1000
        val speedInKmPerHour = speed * 3.6

        val distanceTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.distance)
        distanceTextView.text = String.format("%.2f km", distanceInKm)

        val speedTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.speed)
        speedTextView.text = String.format("%.2f km/h", speedInKmPerHour)
    }
    private fun permissionCheck(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.runapp

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.job.JobParameters
import android.app.job.JobService
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList

class LocationTrackingService : JobService() {

    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val notificationId = 123456
    private val channelId = "location_channel"
    private val locationList = CopyOnWriteArrayList<Location>()

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        createNotificationChannel()

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Location Service")
            .setContentText("Getting location updates")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .build()

        startForeground(notificationId, notification)

        startLocationUpdates()

        // Return true to indicate that you have ongoing work in this job.
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        // This method is called if the job is interrupted before completion.
        // Return true to reschedule the job.
        stopLocationUpdates()
        return true
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Location Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 1000
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                    locationList.add(location)
                }
            }
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,  // Assign the callback here
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    }

    private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }

    fun getLocationList(): List<Location> {
        return locationList
    }

    fun removeLocation(location: Location) {
        locationList.remove(location)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't update UI if app is in foreground?